# Merge csv files to excel in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, merge, automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python: creating excel workbook and dumping csv files as worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705588/python-creating-excel-workbook-and-dumping-csv-files-as-worksheets)

How would you automate the task of taking several CSV files and placing them in a single excel (XLS\XLSX) file so that each CSV is a different sheet, optimally with the same name as the CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.python-excel.org/) is a page that has several python excel libraries.  Pick one that suites your needs.  The library will provide ways of creating tabs and populating each tab.  After doing so, if you still have questions, come back and update your post.  Good luck!