# Reading from a text file and writing to an excel file in Python

Tags: python, excel

I want to read from a specified file in a source code (.map file) and to write the variables from there that have a certain name to an excel workbook. Some hints?

Comment: Welcome to `stackoverflow`. Your question is broad. You need to add some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

It seems [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/) package, allows for writing data to Excel files

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can directly write to an excel workbook, but you can easily create a `CSV` file and then import it to your excel workbook.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705588/python-creating-excel-workbook-and-dumping-csv-files-as-worksheets)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are modules available for Python to help with this. The easy way would be to just write to a .CSV file and then the user can open in Excel as suggested by others. However, if you want to write to a real Excel file check out the [modules here](http://www.python-excel.org).

I have used xlrd to read Excel files before and it's not too difficult to get started with. I haven't yet tried writing to an Excel file with xlwt, but it sounds like this should do what you need. I have found some examples [here](http://scienceoss.com/write-excel-files-with-python-using-xlwt/).

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities here:

1. Create a comma separated value, (csv), or tab separated value file, and read it into excel.
2. Use the tools at [python-excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) to write an excel file directly,
3. Write excel compatible XML files in many ways.
4. Use win32com to open and control excel on the same machine to do the job, [examples](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/).